# libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, apache

I am trying  to load but getting below error

Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_pubcookie.so into server: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
[root@**** lib]# ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_pubcookie.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffccfdf3000)
libssl.so.6 => not found
libcrypto.so.6 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f18befe6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f18bec52000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f18bf420000)
```

i have these files in following path.

```
[root@*** lib]# ls -l *libssl.so.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 10 06:33 libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
[root@*** lib]# ls -l *libcrypto.so.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 10 06:33 libcrypto.so.6 -> libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: You say you have them in "following path" but never say what that path actually is!

Comment: does this `libssl.so.0.9.8e` exist

Comment: and you can add directories to files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. Do an `ldconfig` afterwards and you have a shiny new LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thanks for the reposnse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue .

1.yum search libssl.so.6

Got the packages

2.yum install openssl098e-0.9.8e-20.0.1.el6_7.1.x86_64

libssl.so.6 got installed in /usr/lib64/